# Symfony Controller - How to return XML response?

Tags: php, xml, symfony

I want to return in my `RandomController::indexAction()` an XML Response:

```
return new Response($this->renderView(
    'AcmeRandomBundle:Random:index.xml.twig',
    array(
        'randomParameter' => $randomParameter
    )
));
```

where `index.xml.twig` is like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<randomTag>
    {{ randomParameter }}
</randomTag>
```

When I want to open this action in firefox, I get in firebug:

```
<html>
   <body>
    <randomTag>
        randomValue
    </randomTag>
   </body>
</html>
```

How to return correct XML response?

Comment: How do you build `$randomParameter`?

Comment: this is totally randomly randomed random string, for example $randomParameter = "randomParameter" :P I think it is not matter in this case ;)

Comment: But I don't understand why `randomParameter` remained untranslated by Twig. It should work even the response was not XML but HTML.

Comment: It works. Really. Just Value and Variable Name are the same ;)

Comment: I made edit special for you. Now, value and variable are different.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try adding correct header on the Response Object like:

```
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```

Otherwise add the correct annotation (`defaults`) on your Controller method like this example:

```
 /**
  * @Route("/hello/{name}", defaults={"_format"="xml"}, name="_demo_hello")
  * @Template()
  */
  public function helloAction($name)
  {
     return array('name' => $name);
  }
```

[Look at the guide for further explaination](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_controller.html#using-formats)

Comment: Hi @user3766478 please consider to upvote my answer if you find it useful

Comment: I never new about the _format property of defaults - I'd always had to do away with annotating the template before because I needed to use the response object. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @vladkras if you use annotations xml is enough.

Answer (score 11):

If you have many XmlResponse to return, consider creating your own Response object:

```
<?php

namespace App\Component\HttpFoundation;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class XmlResponse extends Response
{
    public function __construct(?string $content = '', int $status = 200, array $headers = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($content, $status, array_merge($headers, [
            'Content-Type' => 'text/xml',
        ]));
    }
}
```

You can then return `new XmlResponse($xmlBody);` in your controllers.

Comment: IMHO best solution - clean, transparent and no code repetitions